# Any Lie monomial may be written as a linear combination of "simpler" Lie monomials

Tags: lie-algebras

Some definitions:

> A Lie monomial in the elemens of a set $X$ is a finite product of elements of $X$ bracketed by Lie brackets in any manner, e.g. $[[[x_3,[x_1,x_2]],x_3],[x_2,[x_1,x_1]]] $.
>
> A simpler Lie monomial is a Lie monomial bracketed successively from left to right, that is, Lie monomials of the form: $[\cdots[x_1,x_2],x_3],x_4],\cdots,x_k], $ e.g.$[[[x_1,x_2],x_3],x_4].$
>
> The length of a Lie monomial is the number of elements bracketed in it, e.g. $[[[x_1,x_2],x_3],x_4]$ is of length 4.

I am trying to prove the following statement:

*Any Lie monomial lies in the span of simpler lie monomials*

I found this statement is on Reuteneuter's book about Free Lie algebras, althought he doesn't give any demonstration. Well, I'll show what I did until now:

We proceed by induction on the lenght $|w|$  of a Lie monomial $w$. If $|w|=2,$ we have $w=[x,x']$ and there's nothing to prove. We assume for $|w|=k>1$ and consider monomial $w$ of lenght $|w|=k+1.$ Since now $|w|\geq 3, $ we may write $w=[w_1,w_2],$ where $1\leq |w|\leq k$ and $|w_2| = k+1 - |w_1|.$ We can also assume that both $w_1,w_2$ are simpler lie monomials, since their lenght is smaller than $k$ covered by the induction hyphotesis. Notice that if $|w_2| =1,$ we are done. So we may assume that $|w_2|>1$ and write $w_2 = [w_2',x]$, where $w_2'$ is also a simpler lie monomial of lenght $|w_2'| = |w_2|-1 = k-|w_1|$. Now we use the Jacobi identity:

$$w = [w_1,[w_2',x]] = [[w_1,w_2'],x]+[w_2',[w_1,x]].$$

Here comes the **problem**. The induction hyphotesis guarentees that $[w_1,w_2']$ is a simpler lie momomial, since its lenght is $|w_1|+|w_2'| =  k$; therefore, $[[w_1,w_2'],x]$ is also a simpler lie monomial. But what about $[w_2',[w_1,x]]$? Of course $[w_1,x]$ is a simpler one. But I cannot ensure that the bracket $[w_2',[w_1,x]]$ will remain a simpler lie monomial. Also, it's lenght is just $k+1$ which is not covered by the induction hyphotesis. **What now?**

Any help on finding a path to prove this? Thank you.

Comment: What is exactly the difference between a monomial and a "simpler" monomial?

Comment: You can always write everything in a basis of the Lie algebra. Am I missing some point here?

Comment: @jobe For example, $[[e_1,e_2],[e_3,e_4]]$ is a lie monomial, while $[[[e_1,e_2],e_3],e_4]$ is a simpler lie monomial

Comment: @Ennar yes, the elements of $X$ is the basis for the generated Lie algebra. But the algebra generated is the set of all linear combinations of Lie monomials, right? What I am trying to prove is a refinement of this statement, that is, instead of linear combination of maybe more "random" elements, in fact it is a linear combination of simpler elements.

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought $X$ was the whole algebra, not a set of generators.

Comment: I assume that "simpler" means "left-associative" in this case. This should be in any text that studies free Lie algebras, such as the first volume (Chapter 2) of Bourbaki's *Lie groups and Lie algebras* or Reutenauer's *Free Lie algebras*. But I have to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Definitions

$\newcommand{\kk}{\mathbf{k}}$
First, let me restate your notations and definition.

Fix a Lie algebra $L$ over any commutative ring $\mathbf{k}$. The word "span" shall always mean "$\mathbf{k}$-linear span" from now on. If $U$ is a subset of $L$, then $\kk U$ shall denote the span of $U$.

If $U$ and $V$ are two subsets of $L$, then $\left[U, V\right]_0$ shall mean the set of all Lie brackets $\left[u, v\right]$ with $u \in U$ and $v \in V$. This is a subset of $L$.

If $U$ and $V$ are two $\mathbf{k}$-submodules of $L$, then $\left[U, V\right]$ shall mean the span of the set $\left[U, V\right]_0$. This is a $\mathbf{k}$-submodule of $L$ and contains $\left[U, V\right]_0$ as a subset (but is, in general, greater).

Let $X$ be a subset of $L$. Let me restate the definition of Lie monomials as follows:

> **Definition 1.** We define a sequence $\left(B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots\right)$ of subsets of $L$ recursively as follows: We set $B_1 = X$; then, for each $n > 1$, we set $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{a + b = n} \left[B_a, B_b\right]_0$, where the $a$ and $b$ in the big union are meant to range over positive integers.

Thus, $B_1 = X$ and $B_2 = \left[B_1, B_1\right]_0 = \left[X, X\right]_0$ and $B_3 = \left[B_1, B_2\right]_0 \cup \left[B_2, B_1\right]_0 = \left[X, \left[X, X\right]_0\right]_0 \cup \left[\left[X, X\right]_0, X\right]_0$ and $B_4 = \left[B_1, B_3\right]_0 \cup \left[B_2, B_2\right]_0 \cup \left[B_3, B_1\right]_0$ and so on.

> **Definition 2.** Set $B = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup \cdots$. The elements of $B$ are called the *Lie monomials in $X$*. For each $n \geq 1$, the elements of $B_n$ are called the *Lie monomials in $X$ of length $n$*.

Next, I shall define what you call "simpler monomials", but I will call them "left-bracketed Lie monomials" instead:

> **Definition 3.** We define a sequence $\left(C_1, C_2, C_3, \ldots\right)$ of subsets of $L$ recursively as follows: We set $C_1 = X$; then, for each $n > 1$, we set $C_n = \left[C_{n-1}, X\right]_0$.

Thus, $C_1 = X$ and $C_2 = \left[C_1, X\right]_0 = \left[X, X\right]_0$ and $C_3 = \left[C_2, X\right]_0 = \left[\left[X, X\right]_0, X\right]_0$ and $C_4 = \left[C_3, X\right]_0 = \left[\left[\left[X, X\right]_0, X\right]_0, X\right]_0$ and so on.

> **Definition 4.** Set $C = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3 \cup \cdots$. The elements of $C$ are called the *left-bracketed Lie monomials in $X$*.

### 2. The claim and the proof outline

Now, your claim is the following:

> **Theorem 1.** We have $B \subseteq \kk C$.

The proof is easiest made using the following definition:

> **Definition 5.** We define a sequence $\left(L_1, L_2, L_3, \ldots\right)$ of $\mathbf{k}$-submodules subsets of $L$ recursively as follows: We set $L_1 = \kk X$; then, for each $n > 1$, we set $L_n = \left[L_{n-1}, \kk X\right]$.

Thus, $L_1 = \kk X$ and $L_2 = \left[L_1, \kk X\right] = \left[\kk X, \kk X\right]$ and $L_3 = \left[L_2, \kk X\right] = \left[\left[\kk X, \kk X\right], \kk X\right]$ and so on.

Now, let me split Theorem 1 into the following bite-sized pieces:

> **Proposition 2.** We have $L_n = \kk C_n$ for each $n \geq 1$.
>
> **Proposition 3.** We have $\left[L_a, L_b\right] \subseteq L_{a+b}$ for any $a \geq 1$ and $b \geq 1$.
>
> **Proposition 4.** We have $B_n \subseteq L_n$ for each $n \geq 1$.

See below for the detailed proofs of these three propositions as well as the derivation of Theorem 1 from them. But first, here are hints that should suffice if you have any experience with the Lie algebra axioms:

Proposition 2 is proven by straightforward induction on $n$.

To prove Proposition 3, we proceed by induction on $a$. In the induction step, we assume that Proposition 3 is true for $a-1$, and intend to prove it for $a$. It suffices to show that $\left[\left[x, y\right], z\right] \in L_{a+b}$ for all $x \in L_{a-1}$, $y \in X$ and $z \in L_b$ (because $L_a = \left[L_{a-1}, L\right]$ is spanned by elements of the form $\left[x, y\right]$ with $x \in L_{a-1}$ and $y \in X$). But this follows by applying the Jacobi identity
\begin{align}
\left[\left[x, y\right], z\right]
= \left[\left[x, z\right], y\right] - \left[x, \left[z, y\right]\right]
\end{align}
and realizing that both addends $\left[\left[x, z\right], y\right]$ and $- \left[x, \left[z, y\right]\right]$ on the right hand side belong to $L_{a+b}$ (indeed, we have $\left[x, z\right] \in \left[L_{a-1}, L_b\right] \subseteq L_{a+b-1}$ (by the induction hypothesis) and thus $\left[\left[x, z\right], y\right] \in \left[L_{a+b-1}, \kk X\right] = L_{a+b}$ (by the definition of $L_{a+b}$), and we also have $\left[z, y\right] \in \left[L_b, \kk X\right] = L_{b+1}$ (by the definition of $L_{b+1}$) and therefore $\left[x, \left[z, y\right]\right] \in \left[L_{a-1}, L_{b+1}\right] \subseteq L_{a+b}$ (by the induction hypothesis)). So Proposition 3 follows by induction.

Proposition 4 is proven by strong induction on $n$, using Proposition 3.

Combining Proposition 2 with Proposition 4, we obtain $B_n \subseteq L_n = \kk C_n$ for each $n \geq 1$. Thus, $B \subseteq \kk C$, so that Theorem 1 is proven.

### 3. Formal proofs

Let me prove these Propositions 2, 3 and 4 in detail, just to make sure
everything is exactly as I claimed (you have most likely proven them yourself
by now). This has turned out to be even duller than expected.

We will tacitly use the observation that if $U$ and $V$ are two subsets of
$L$, and if $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, then $\left[  u,v\right]  \in\left[
U,V\right]  $. (Indeed, if $U$ and $V$ are two subsets of $L$, then the
definition of $\left[  U,V\right]  $ shows that $\left[  U,V\right]  =\left(
\text{the span of }\left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  =\kk \left(  \left[
U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $. Thus, if $U$ and $V$ are two subsets of $L$, and
if $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, then we have $\left[  u,v\right]  \in\left[
U,V\right]  _0 \subseteq\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)
=\left[  U,V\right]  $.)

We shall use two simple lemmas:

> **Lemma 5.** Let $S$ be a subset of $L$. Let $M$ be a $\kk$-submodule
> of $L$. If $S\subseteq M$, then $\kk S\subseteq M$.

*Proof of Lemma 5.* Recall that $\kk S$ is the span of $S$, and thus is
the smallest $\kk$-submodule of $L$ that contains $S$ as a subset.
Hence, any $\kk$-submodule of $L$ that contains $S$ as a subset must
contain $\kk S$ as a subset. Applying this to the $\kk$-submodule
$M$, we conclude that $M$ contains $\kk S$ as a subset if $M$ contains
$S$ as a subset. In other words, if $S\subseteq M$, then $\kk S\subseteq
M$. This proves Lemma 5. $\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 6.** Let $U$ and $V$ be two subsets of $L$. Then, $\left[
> \kk U,\kk V\right]  =\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]
> _0 \right)  $.

*Proof of Lemma 6.* Recall that $\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  $ is
the span of the subset $\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 $ (by the
definition of $\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  $). In other words,
$\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  =\kk \left(  \left[
\kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 \right)  $. Hence, $\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  $ is a $\kk$-submodule of $L$ and satisfies
$\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 \subseteq\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  $.

Let $r\in\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 $ be arbitrary. We shall
show that $r\in\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $.

Indeed, we have $r\in\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 $; in other
words, $r=\left[  u,v\right]  $ for some $u\in\kk U$ and some
$v\in\kk V$ (by the definition of $\left[  \kk U,\kk 
V\right]  _0 $). Consider these $u$ and $v$.

We have $u\in\kk U$. In other words, $u$ is a $\kk$-linear
combination of the elements of $U$ (by the definition of the span
$\kk U$). In other words, $u=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_{i}u_{i}$ for some
finite set $I$ and some families $\left(  \lambda_{i}\right)  _{i\in I}
\in\kk ^{I}$ and $\left(  u_{i}\right)  _{i\in I}\in U^{I}$. Consider
this $I$ and these families.

We have $v\in\kk U$. In other words, $v$ is a $\kk$-linear
combination of the elements of $V$ (by the definition of the span
$\kk V$). In other words, $v=\sum_{j\in J}\mu_{j}v_{j}$ for some finite
set $J$ and some families $\left(  \mu_{j}\right)  _{j\in J}\in\kk ^{J}$
and $\left(  v_{j}\right)  _{j\in J}\in V^{J}$. Consider this $J$ and these families.

Now,
\begin{align*}
r  &  =\left[  u,v\right]  =\left[  \sum_{i\in I}\lambda_{i}u_{i},\sum_{j\in
J}\mu_{j}v_{j}\right]  \qquad\left(  \text{since }u=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda
_{i}u_{i}\text{ and }v=\sum_{j\in J}\mu_{j}v_{j}\right) \\
&  =\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_{i}\sum_{j\in J}\mu_{j}\left[  u_{i},v_{j}\right]
\qquad\left(  \text{since the Lie bracket is }\kk \text{-bilinear}
\right) \\
&  =\sum_{\left(  i,j\right)  \in I\times J}\lambda_{i}\mu_{j}
\underbrace{\left[  u_{i},v_{j}\right]  }_{\substack{\in\left[  U,V\right]
_0 \\\text{(since }u_{i}\in U\text{ and }v_{j}\in V\text{)}}}\in\sum_{\left(
i,j\right)  \in I\times J}\lambda_{i}\mu_{j}\left[  U,V\right]  _0 .
\end{align*}
Thus, $r$ is a $\kk$-linear combination of elements of $\left[
U,V\right]  _0 $. In other words, $r$ belongs to the span of $\left[
U,V\right]  _0 $. In other words, $r\in\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]
_0 \right)  $ (because $\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $
is the span of $\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $).

Now, forget that we fixed $r$. We thus have proven that $r\in\kk \left(
\left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $ for each $r\in\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  _0 $. In other words, $\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  _0 \subseteq\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]
_0 \right)  $. Thus, Lemma 5 (applied to $M=\kk \left(  \left[
U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $ and $S=\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]
_0 $) yields that $\kk \left(  \left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]
_0 \right)  \subseteq\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $.
Now, recall that $\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  =\kk \left(
\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  _0 \right)  \subseteq\kk 
\left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $.

On the other hand, let $q\in\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $. We shall show that
$q\in\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  $.

In fact, we have $q\in\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $; in other words, $q=\left[
\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}\right]  $ for some $\widetilde{u}\in U$ and some
$\widetilde{v}\in V$ (by the definition of $\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $).
Consider these $\widetilde{u}$ and $\widetilde{v}$. From $\widetilde{u}\in
U\subseteq\kk U$ and $\widetilde{v}\in V\subseteq\kk V$, we obtain
$\left[  \widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}\right]  \in\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  $. Thus, $q=\left[  \widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}\right]
\in\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  $.

Forget that we fixed $q$. We thus have proven that $q\in\left[  \kk 
U,\kk V\right]  $ for each $q\in\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $. In other
words, $\left[  U,V\right]  _0 \subseteq\left[  \kk U,\kk 
V\right]  $. Thus, Lemma 5 (applied to $M=\left[  \kk U,\kk 
V\right]  $ and $S=\left[  U,V\right]  _0 $) yields that $\kk \left(
\left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  \subseteq\left[  \kk U,\kk 
V\right]  $. Combining this with $\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]
\subseteq\kk \left(  \left[  U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $, we obtain
$\left[  \kk U,\kk V\right]  =\kk \left(  \left[
U,V\right]  _0 \right)  $. This proves Lemma 6. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Proposition 2.* We shall prove Proposition 2 by induction on $n$:

*Induction base:* The definition of $C_{1}$ yields $C_{1}=X$. The definition
of $L_{1}$ yields $L_{1}=\kk \underbrace{X}_{=C_{1}}=\kk C_{1}$.
In other words, Proposition 2 holds for $n=1$. This completes the induction base.

*Induction step:* Fix a positive integer $m>1$. Assume that Proposition 2
holds for $n=m-1$. We must prove that Proposition 2 holds for $n=m$.

We have assumed that Proposition 2 holds for $n=m-1$. In other words,
$L_{m-1}=\kk C_{m-1}$. The recursive definition of the $C_{n}$ yields
$C_{m}=\left[  C_{m-1},X\right]  _0 $. Hence, $\kk C_{m}=\kk 
\left(  \left[  C_{m-1},X\right]  _0 \right)  $. But Lemma 6 (applied to
$U=C_{m-1}$ and $V=X$) yields $\left[  \kk C_{m-1},\kk X\right]
=\kk \left(  \left[  C_{m-1},X\right]  _0 \right)  $. Comparing these
two equalities, we obtain $\kk C_{m}=\left[  \kk C_{m-1}
,\kk X\right]  $.

But the recursive definition of the $L_{n}$ yields $L_{m}=\left[
\underbrace{L_{m-1}}_{=\kk C_{m-1}},\kk X\right]  =\left[
\kk C_{m-1},\kk X\right]  $. Comparing these two equalities, we
obtain $L_{m}=\kk C_{m}$. In other words, Proposition 2 holds for $n=m$.
This completes the induction step. Thus, Proposition 2 is proven.
$\blacksquare$

*Proof of Proposition 3.* We shall prove Proposition 3 by induction on $a$:

*Induction base:* Let $b\geq1$ be an integer. We shall prove that $\left[
L_{1},L_{b}\right]  \subseteq L_{1+b}$.

Indeed, the recursive definition of the $L_{n}$ yields $L_{b+1}=\left[
L_{b},\kk X\right]  $ and $L_{1}=\kk X$.

Let $r\in\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 $ be arbitrary. We shall show that
$r\in L_{b+1}$.

Indeed, we have $r\in\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 $; in other words,
$r=\left[  u,v\right]  $ for some $u\in L_{1}$ and some $v\in L_{b}$ (by the
definition of $\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 $). Consider these $u$ and $v$.

We have $\left[  \underbrace{v}_{\in L_{b}},\underbrace{u}_{\in L_{1}}\right]
\in\left[  L_{b},\underbrace{L_{1}}_{=\kk X}\right]  =\left[
L_{b},\kk X\right]  =L_{b+1}$ (since $L_{b+1}=\left[  L_{b}
,\kk X\right]  $). But $r=\left[  u,v\right]  =-\left[  v,u\right]  $
(since the Lie bracket is antisymmetric). Hence, $r=-\underbrace{\left[
v,u\right]  }_{\in L_{b+1}}\in-L_{b+1}\subseteq L_{b+1}$ (since $L_{b+1}$ is a
$\kk$-submodule of $L$).

Now, forget that we fixed $r$. We thus have proven that $r\in L_{b+1}$ for
each $r\in\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 $. In other words, $\left[
L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 \subseteq L_{b+1}$. Hence, Lemma 5 (applied to
$M=L_{b+1}$ and $S=\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 $) yields that
$\kk \left(  \left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 \right)  \subseteq L_{b+1}
$. But $\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  $ is the span of $\left[  L_{1}
,L_{b}\right]  _0 $ (by the definition of $\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  $); in
other words, $\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  =\kk \left(  \left[
L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 \right)  $. Hence, $\left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]
=\kk \left(  \left[  L_{1},L_{b}\right]  _0 \right)  \subseteq
L_{b+1}=L_{1+b}$.

Now, forget that we fixed $b$. We thus have proven that $\left[  L_{1}
,L_{b}\right]  \subseteq L_{1+b}$ for all $b\geq1$. In other words,
Proposition 3 holds for $a=1$. This completes the induction base.

*Induction step:* Fix an integer $c>1$. Assume that Proposition 3 holds for
$a=c-1$. We must prove that Proposition 3 holds for $a=c$.

Let $b\geq1$ be an integer. We shall show that $\left[  L_{c},L_{b}\right]
\subseteq L_{c+b}$.

Proposition 2 (applied to $n=b$) yields $L_{b}=\kk C_{b}$. Proposition 2
(applied to $n=c$) yields $L_{c}=\kk C_{c}$. Now,
\begin{align*}
\left[  \underbrace{L_{c}}_{=\kk C_{c}},\underbrace{L_{b}}
_{=\kk C_{b}}\right]  =\left[  \kk C_{c},\kk C_{b}\right]
=\kk \left(  \left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 \right)
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 6, applied to $U=C_{c}$ and $V=C_{b}$).

Now, let $r\in\left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 $ be arbitrary. We shall show
that $r\in C_{c+b}$.

We have $r\in\left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 $. In other words, $r=\left[
u,z\right]  $ for some $u\in C_{c}$ and some $z\in C_{b}$ (by the definition
of $\left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 $). Consider these $u$ and $z$.

We have $u\in C_{c}=\left[  C_{c-1},X\right]  _0 $ (by the recursive
definition of the $C_{n}$, since $c>1$). In other words, $u=\left[
x,y\right]  $ for some $x\in C_{c-1}$ and some $y\in X$ (by the definition of
$\left[  C_{c-1},X\right]  _0 $). Consider these $x$ and $y$.

The recursive definition of the $L_{n}$ yields $L_{c+b}=\left[  L_{c+b-1}
,\kk X\right]  $ and $L_{b+1}=\left[  L_{b},\kk X\right]  $.

We can apply Proposition 3 to $c-1$ instead of $a$ (since we have assumed that
Proposition 3 holds for $a=c-1$). We thus obtain $\left[  L_{c-1}
,L_{b}\right]  \subseteq L_{\left(  c-1\right)  +b}=L_{c+b-1}$.

We can apply Proposition 3 to $c-1$ and $b+1$ instead of $a$ and $b$ (since we
have assumed that Proposition 3 holds for $a=c-1$). We thus obtain $\left[
L_{c-1},L_{b+1}\right]  \subseteq L_{\left(  c-1\right)  +\left(  b+1\right)
}=L_{c+b}$.

Proposition 2 (applied to $n=c-1$) yields $L_{c-1}=\kk C_{c-1}$. From
$x\in C_{c-1}\subseteq\kk C_{c-1}=L_{c-1}$ and $z\in C_{b}
\subseteq\kk C_{b}=L_{b}$, we obtain $\left[  \underbrace{x}_{\in
L_{c-1}},\underbrace{z}_{\in L_{b}}\right]  \in\left[  L_{c-1},L_{b}\right]
\subseteq L_{c+b-1}$. Combining this with $y\in X\subseteq\kk X$, we
obtain $\left[  \underbrace{\left[  x,z\right]  }_{\in L_{c+b-1}
},\underbrace{y}_{\in\kk X}\right]  \in\left[  L_{c+b-1},\kk 
X\right]  =L_{c+b}$.

From $z\in L_{b}$ and $y\in X\subseteq\kk X$, we obtain $\left[
\underbrace{z}_{\in L_{b}},\underbrace{y}_{\in\kk X}\right]  \in\left[
L_{b},\kk X\right]  =L_{b+1}$. Hence, $\left[  \underbrace{x}_{\in
L_{c-1}},\underbrace{\left[  z,y\right]  }_{\in L_{b+1}}\right]  \in\left[
L_{c-1},L_{b+1}\right]  \subseteq L_{c+b}$.

But recall that
\begin{align*}
r &  =\left[  \underbrace{u}_{=\left[  x,y\right]  },z\right]  =\left[
\left[  x,y\right]  ,z\right]  =\underbrace{\left[  \left[  x,z\right]
,y\right]  }_{\in L_{c+b}}-\underbrace{\left[  x,\left[  z,y\right]  \right]
}_{\in L_{c+b}}\\
&  \qquad\qquad\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{since the Jacobi identity yields}\\
\left[  \left[  x,z\right]  ,y\right]  =\left[  \left[  x,y\right]  ,z\right]
+\left[  x,\left[  z,y\right]  \right]
\end{array}
\right)  \\
&  \in L_{c+b}-L_{c+b}\subseteq L_{c+b}\qquad\left(  \text{since }
L_{c+b}\text{ is a }\kk \text{-submodule of }L\right)  .
\end{align*}

Now, forget that we fixed $r$. We thus have shown that $r\in L_{c+b}$ for each
$r\in\left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 $. In other words, $\left[  C_{c}
,C_{b}\right]  _0 \subseteq L_{c+b}$.

Hence, Lemma 5 (applied to $M=L_{c+b}$ and $S=\left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]
_0 $) yields that $\kk \left(  \left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 \right)
\subseteq L_{c+b}$. Now, recall that $\left[  L_{c},L_{b}\right]
=\kk \left(  \left[  C_{c},C_{b}\right]  _0 \right)  \subseteq L_{c+b}$.

Now, forget that we fixed $b$. We thus have proven that $\left[  L_{c}
,L_{b}\right]  \subseteq L_{c+b}$ for all $b\geq1$. In other words,
Proposition 3 holds for $a=c$. This completes the induction step. Hence,
Proposition 3 is proven by induction. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Proposition 4.* We shall prove Proposition 4 by strong induction on
$n$. Thus, we fix an integer $m\geq1$. We assume that Proposition 4 holds for
all $n<m$. We want to prove that Proposition 4 holds for $n=m$ as well.

Let $r\in B_{m}$. We shall prove that $r\in L_{m}$.

If $m=1$, then this holds for easy reasons (in fact, if $m=1$, then
$B_{m}=B_{1}=X\subseteq\kk X=L_{1}=L_{m}$ (since $1=m$), and therefore
$r\in B_{m}\subseteq L_{m}$). Thus, for the rest of this proof, we WLOG assume
that we don't have $m=1$. Hence, $m>1$.

Thus, the recursive definition of $B_{m}$ yields $B_{m}=\bigcup\limits_{a+b=m}
\left[  B_{a},B_{b}\right]  _0 $. Hence, $r\in B_{m}=\bigcup\limits_{a+b=m}
\left[  B_{a},B_{b}\right]  _0 $. In other words, $r\in\left[  B_{a}
,B_{b}\right]  _0 $ for some pair $\left(  a,b\right)  $ of positive integers
satisfying $a+b=m$. Consider this pair $\left(  a,b\right)  $. We have $a>0$
(since $a$ is a positive integer) and thus $a+b>b$, so that $b<a+b=m$.
Similarly, $a<m$.

We have assumed that Proposition 4 holds for all $n<m$. Hence, we can apply
Proposition 4 to $n=a$ (since $a<m$). We thus obtain $B_{a}\subseteq L_{a}$.
The same argument (applied to $b$ instead of $a$) yields $B_{b}\subseteq
L_{b}$.

But $r\in\left[  B_{a},B_{b}\right]  _0 $. In other words, $r=\left[
u,v\right]  $ for some $u\in B_{a}$ and some $v\in B_{b}$ (by the definition
of $\left[  B_{a},B_{b}\right]  _0 $). Consider these $u$ and $v$. We have
$u\in B_{a}\subseteq L_{a}$ and $v\in B_{b}\subseteq L_{b}$. Now, $r=\left[
\underbrace{u}_{\in L_{a}},\underbrace{v}_{\in L_{b}}\right]  \in\left[
L_{a},L_{b}\right]  \subseteq L_{a+b}$ (by Proposition 3). In view of $a+b=m$,
this rewrites as $r\in L_{m}$.

Now, forget that we fixed $r$. We thus have proven that $r\in L_{m}$ for each
$r\in B_{m}$. In other words, $B_{m}\subseteq L_{m}$. In other words,
Proposition 4 holds for $n=m$. This completes the induction proof. Thus,
Proposition 4 is proven by strong induction. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Let $r\in B$. Thus, $r\in B=B_{1}\cup B_{2}\cup
B_{3}\cup\cdots$. In other words, $r\in B_{n}$ for some integer $n\geq1$. Fix
this $n$.

Now, $r\in B_{n}\subseteq L_{n}$ (by Proposition 4), so that $r\in
L_{n}=\kk C_{n}$ (by Proposition 2). But $C_{n}\subseteq C_{1}\cup
C_{2}\cup C_{3}\cup\cdots=C$ (since $C=C_{1}\cup C_{2}\cup C_{3}\cup\cdots$),
so that $r\in\kk \underbrace{C_{n}}_{\subseteq C}\subseteq\kk C$.

Now, forget that we fixed $r$. We thus have proven that $r\in\kk C$ for
each $r\in B$. In other words, $B\subseteq\kk C$. This proves Theorem 1.
$\blacksquare$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort. I ain't got time to check precisely all demonstrations, but the path seems good. As soons as I do it, I'll give you the points. Hm, I would like to ask you: where did you study those stuff about lie algebras?

Comment: @math.h: Writing this thing was very automatic (great chore when one's brain is tired) and involved a lot of copy-paste, as you can see by the repetitive formulations. I learned some of this stuff from [Hartmut Laue, *Freie algebraische Strukturen*](http://www.math.uni-kiel.de/algebra/laue/vorlesungen/frei/freiealgstr.pdf) (the chapter on Lie algebras is mostly independent of the free groups chapter, which I have never read). But Proposition 3 (the crux of the argument) is a known fact; I had to prove very similar things in http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/r2t.pdf .

Comment: I know this post is very old, but assuming $B$ is the nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{\nu,n}$ on $n$ generators of nilpotence $\nu$, is there a way to explicitly describe the Jacobi identity using the left-associative generators?
If you prefer posting an answer, [this is the relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768559/jacobi-identity-free-nilpotent-lie-algebra#comment7761501_3768559)

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation: I'm afraid I don't know anything about it (if what you're looking for are explicit formulas for expanding the Lie bracket of two left-associative iterated Lie brackets in terms of left-associative iterated Lie brackets).

Answer (score 2):

Write $[x_1, \dots, x_n] = [\cdots[x_1, x_2], \dots x_n]$.
By the Jacobi formula,
$$[x, [y, z]] = [x, y, z] - [x, z, y].$$ Induction on the length of $w$ then shows the statement holds for any bracket $[x, w]$ with $x$ a simpler monomial, as $[x_1, \dots, x_n] = [[x_1, \dots, x_k], x_{k+1}, \dots, x_n]$. But $$[[x, y], z] = -[z, [x, y]] + [y, [x, z]],$$
so another induction on the length of $x$ proves the result for an arbitrary bracket $[x, w]$.